# Question about Faraday Cage

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

I am aware that faraday cage is used to protect electronics from damage.  However, if I put a signal generator in a faraday cage and turn the signal generator on, can the frequency still be picked up/detected by external sources?  Or will the faraday cage block the frequency signals sent out by the generator?

Comment: This is an excellent first question because Faraday mostly worked with DC fields but we use the term now in the context of AC. It also reminds me of "put the cage next to the tiger, now invert the space" joke (something like that at least, I forget), for who is truly inside the faraday cage, and who is outside it?

Comment: Don't feel bad if it is ultimately decided to be a duplicate of [Does a Faraday cage block outgoing signals?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/269672/83380) or a similar question. That happens frequently, especially for first time users of the site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a Faraday cage block outgoing signals?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/269672/)